I made a tool for automatically generating the text for the Screenshot of the Week
I made a GUI interface using Visual Basic to track the - wait, sorry, no that's not what I did. What I actually did was create a tool for automatically generating the text for the Screenshot of the Week (in C#, not Visual Basic, since I practice self-care).

The tool is pretty simple. Fill in the fields, and click "Copy to Clipboard". You then paste that into a new question an Arqade, add a title and tags, and you're good to post the new SOTW. Since the mods aren't always the ones to post the SOTW, I figured it would be a good idea to share with the community at large.
One thing to be aware of is that it doesn't include a time for when the SOTW week ends, just the date. I did this since in reality we never respected the "official" time anyways. Sometimes we were early, but usually we were late, so I figured might as well just include the date only.
You can download the tool here, and the source code is hosted here. The EXE isn't signed or anything like that, so Windows will yell at you that it's dangerous to run this, but I promise it's not a virus. Speaking of which, the tool is currently windows only. There's also a chance it won't actually work if you don't have .NET installed on your PC, in which case I'll need to create the EXE in a different manner.
If you have any suggestions on how it can be improved, feel free to share them.

That video had to be some targeted Microsoft advertising

The tool works perfectly for me with Wine on Linux. (But the virus part seems to have broken, my system is still running.)

Now we just need this, but for Hall of Fame entries.

@Daemons I could actually build that into this same tool. Shouldn't take long to do, actually. I'll make that change, then update this post. Thanks for the idea!

@Wipqozn And if we want to be really fancy (which is just another word for lazy), we could webscrape the post by giving the program a link, and have it do everything for us. Probably against the terms of service, but if it's not... [wink]

What a nice idea, thanks! This could be transformed in a Javascript/Angular form that creates the text to be copied, and maybe host that on Stackblitz, to avoid the downloading of a tool from an "unsafe" source.

Javascript can still make a virus... Right?

Yes, but I think the idea here is to run it on a StackExchange-specific system, which gives easy access to its data and probably has tons of safeguards against viruses.

Careful, one day these tools will replace us

@arghtype Ah, a day off...

Man, I only see this now, this is awesome!
